# How to download videos from pages with flash players algorithmically?

Tags: flash, video, stream, video-streaming

Programs like http://netvideohunter.com can recognize available mp4 streams even if they are "hidden" (a flash player requests for them). How to they do it? How I can recognize and filter these streams myself?
what are the potential techniques that are used for detecting videos?
How could be such an extension written(provided I wanted to implement exactly the same functionality)?

For now I'm always decompiling the flash player to detect the url, but it's really a painful way...

What are the heuristics that can be done to detect the videos here?
I'm pretty sure there are some heuristics used and the sites aren't handled "per case", because the downloader detected the videos even from some local sites in my mothertongue.

So to clarify: I'm NOT interested in programs that do it, BUT in techniques employed by finding the (flv, mp3) streams...

Comment: thank you for the downvotes without exlpaining the reason. this q has already been posted onother overflows and I was advices to use SO.

Answer (score 0):

Analyze the requests made by the browser with a plugin or proxy/analyze packets with a standalone app.